# HDFS Space Quota - What if the Parent folder has less quota compared to its child folders

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, quota

Reg HDFS Space Quota - Cloudera

If I have a folder A in HDFS and inside A there is another folder B.

Space Quota for A - 100 MB

Space Quota for B - 200 MB

If I try to copy a file of size 150MB to B, is to going to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsQuotaAdminGuide.html#Space_Quotas):

> The space quota is a hard limit on the number of bytes used by files
>   in **the tree** rooted at that directory.

So in general, you can't put a file larger than the quota of a parent directory into a sub-directory or any of its children.

In your specific case, the largest file you can put into `B` is 100MB, on two conditions:

1. replication factor for the file is set to 1, and
2. `dfs.blocksize` of the file is =100MB (or `dfs.blocksize` x N = 100MB) since according to the same document

> Block allocations fail if the quota would not allow **a full block**
>   to be written.